# How to understand 之所以

Tags: grammar, mandarin, phrase

I’m reading Randall Munroe’s “What If 2” in Mandarin. (It’s the author of the popular cartoon xkcd.com)

There’s a chapter about placing a house-sized Jupiter in the middle of a neighborhood.

The sentence reads:

> 一个20,000摄氏度的氢球将以不可思议的压力向外扩张。真实的木星**之所以**没有爆炸，是因为 […]

Roughly: “A 20,000 degree ball of hydrogen will expand outward due to unbelievable pressure. The reason why the real Jupiter doesn’t explode is because…”

I understand that 之所以 means “the reason why”, and my dictionary confirms that.

However I don’t think 之所以 should be intended as one single word. Intuitively I can understand it as 之 + 所以 （therefore), however I’m not fully sure why it’s used as a noun modifier (木星之所以）

Can someone explain the grammar behind this construction?

Comment: There's also the chengyu [不知所以](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=不知所以) = "to not know the reason / to not know what to do".

Comment: 之所以……是因为…… is more or less a fixed phrase (固定搭配) meaning “the reason why … is because …”.  Etymologically, 之所以 is comprised of 之 + 所以, but in contemporary Mandarin, it almost always occurs as a fixed phrase together with 是因为, known as a pair of “connectives” (关联词) along with 因为……所以……, 虽然……但是……, 不仅……而且……, and so on in Chinese school grammar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

木星(subject)

之('s)

所以(reason)

没有爆炸 (statement)

木星[之所以]没有爆炸 = [The reason why] Jupiter not exploded

~

美國[之所以]要援助烏克蘭，原因是為了打擊俄羅斯

[The reason way] the U.S. aids Ukraine is to weaken Russia

Comment: Is 所以 actually used as a noun in this case?

Comment: 所以 is acting as a noun for "reason" here. "之所以" = "reason of"

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. 之 + 所以 = it + therefore.

- 木星(Jupiter)之(it)所以(therefore)没有爆炸(didn't explode), 是因为(was because)...

Comment: "it therefore" isn't grammatical English though. I'm not sure what you are trying to say.

Comment: Yes, "it" shall be dropped in English. But, my main point is that "之" can be used as a pronoun, here it equates to "它" (it).

Comment: I don't think this is a correct explanation.

Comment: Ignore the previous answer, try this: "Jupiter, therefore it didn't explode, is because of......", or this: "Jupiter, for the reason it didn't explode, is because of......"

Answer (score 0):

我今天`之所以`迟到是因为路上堵车了.

`The reason` I was late today is that there was traffic on the road.